# How does Einstein's oscillatory & quantum structure of radiation from 1909 relate to modern physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, electromagnetic-radiation, wavefunction, photoelectric-effect

In his 1909 lecture [The Development of Our Views on the Composition and Essence of Radiation](https://en.wikisource.org/?curid=53013) Einstein discusses two structures of "radiation":

> As far as I know, no mathematical theory has been advanced that does justice to both its oscillatory structure and its quantum structure, which we derived from the first term of the above formula.

Discussing the quantum structure he says

> In addition to the spatial irregularities in the distribution of radiation's energy that arise from the oscillation theory, there are also other irregularities in the same spatial distribution that completely dominate the first-mentioned irregularities when the energy density of the radiation is small

And finally:

> this conception seems to me the most natural: that the manifestation of light's electromagnetic waves is constrained at singularity points, like the manifestation of electrostatic fields in the theory of the electron. (...)  the entire energy of the electromagnetic field could be viewed as localized in these singularities, just like the old theory of action-at-a-distance. I imagine to myself, each such singular point surrounded by a field that has essentially the same character as a plane wave, and whose amplitude decreases with the distance between the singular points. If many such singularities are separated by a distance small with respect to the dimensions of the field of one singular point, their fields will be superimposed, and will form in their totality an oscillating field

Einstein to my understanding is pointing at a new, quantized "oscillatory theory of light", in which the oscillation can be understood as effect of an underlying quantized field.

How did later physics until today continue these thoughts?

Is modern quantum field theory the missing mathematical model for what Einstein is imagining here?

Or does quantum mechanics, the wave function and Schrödinger equation, already formalize these concepts?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about the history of physics which is more appropriate on History of Science and Mathematics SE.

Comment: "Or does quantum mechanics, the wave function and Schrödinger equation, already formalize these concepts?". Yes, they do.

Comment: Can you explain how the wave function and later Schrödingers time dependent equation generalized Einstein's idea of localized, superimposed field that "form (...) an oscillating field"? What fundamental concepts does Einstein's quote not yet discuss?

Comment: And is it not rather the QFT of QED that formalized these concepts of how "the electromagnetic field could be viewed"?

Comment: For reference/easier jumping, [hsm.se] is the Stack Exchange site that Sammy refers you to.

Comment: Seems like a perfect physics question. It was Einstein, not Born, who conceived of probability waves as energy densities (first for a gas of photons). Secondly, QFT/QED gives us the mathematical formalism Einstein is alluding to here. Of course, most people don't see to understand that Schrodinger likely never comes up with his wave equation without Einsteins work on probability waves (see Abraham Pais, Subtle is the Lord).